# Assertion Failed error for Ogre RenderWindow

Tags: c++, qt, assertion, ogre

I am trying to embed Ogre in Qt using the code given at:
https://github.com/gklingler/QOgreWidget

And it runs fine on my system without any trouble but when I try to add the same in my Qt application, I get the following error:

```
SceneManagerFactory for type 'PCZSceneManager' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'PCZLight' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Portal' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'AntiPortal' registered.
PCZone Factory Type 'ZoneType_Octree' registered
SceneManagerFactory for type 'OctreeSceneManager' registered.
app: ../app/ogre/ogrebasewidget.cpp:45: OgreBaseWidget::OgreBaseWidget(Ogre::Root*,                     OgreEventHandler*, QWidget*): Assertion `ogreWinId' failed.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

The error points to this code snippet:

```
Ogre::String winHandle;

winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long) (QX11Info::display()));
winHandle += " : ";
winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long) (QX11Info::appScreen()));
winHandle += " : ";
winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long) (winId()));

Ogre::NameValuePairList params;
params["parentWindowHandle"] = winHandle;
params["FSAA"] = Ogre::String("8");

int w = width();
int h = height();
mOgreRenderWindow = mOgreRoot->createRenderWindow("OgreWidget_RenderWindow",
                                                  qMax(w, 640),
                                                  qMax(h, 480),
                                                  false, &params);
mOgreRenderWindow->setActive(true);
mOgreRenderWindow->setVisible(true);

WId ogreWinId = 0x0;
mOgreRenderWindow->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW", &ogreWinId);
assert(ogreWinId);
QWidget::create(ogreWinId);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
```

I have included `<cassert>` in the header. Help me figure this out. :(

Comment: Cross-post: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=81728

Comment: I want to resolve it as soon as possible. I don't consider it an issue to ask for help at different forums.

Comment: Yes, but please make it clear next time, as explained here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159/1947205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it was giving this error.
I had the older version(1.7.4) of Ogre installed as well along with the newer 1.9 version.

So I purged this older version from my system and voila it worked like a charm.